# 吃 VS 吃掉 difference

Tags: difference

I just saw the Chinese poster of Japanese animation movie called "I Want to Eat Your Pancreas".

This is its title in Chinese :

> 我想吃掉你的胰脏

I wonder why they used 吃掉 instead of just 吃. Is there any difference between 吃 and 吃掉?

Answer (score 4):

吃 only means eat, while 吃掉 means eating the whole thing.
吃掉你的胰臟 means that eating the whole pancreas.
吃掉 is also slightly more derogatory than only 吃.